# Less: Is there a difference between @arguments and ellipsis (...)?

Tags: parameters, arguments, less, mixins, ellipsis

I was just wondering because it came up in our project today.
There doesn't seem to be a difference when implementing a mixin and capturing the parameters with @arguments or ellipsis, couldn't find anything useful on google either so I'm asking here.

Example:

```
.transition(@arguments) {
    -webkit-transition: @arguments;
    -moz-transition: @arguments;
    transition: @arguments;
}
```

or

```
.transition(...) {
    -webkit-transition: @arguments;
    -moz-transition: @arguments;
    transition: @arguments;
}
```

Use:

```
.transition(left 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease);
```

Is there any advantage to either of these implementations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There doesn't seem to be a difference

There's actually, did you try to compile your code?
These are quite different mixins:

```
// this is a mixin definition with a variable number of arguments
.a(...) {
    // here you use built-in @arguments variable
    a-value: @arguments;
}

// this is a mixin definition with a single argument
.b(@arguments) {
    // here you use a variable you've just declared in mixin's argument list
    // (and it's not the built-in @arguments!)
    b-value: @arguments;
}

test {
    .a(1, 2, 3); // OK
    .b(1, 2, 3); // Error
}
```

Or in other words:

```
.a(@arguments) {
    a-value: @arguments;
}
```

is equal to:

```
.a(@x) {
    @arguments: @x; // defines a new variable that overrides the built-in one
    a-value: @arguments;
}
```

---

There's also another way to declare a variable argument list: `.mixin(@whatever...)`.
Basically it is the same as `(...)` but it is useful when you need something like:

```
.c(@head, @tail...) {
    head: @head;
    tail: @tail;
}

test {
    .c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only difference between those two is that `transition(...)` accepts any number of arguments, while `transition(@arguments)` accepts only one argument.

`@arguments` (in mixin **body**) contains all passed arguments and does not depend on what are original mixins parameters, as long as one of them isn't called `arguments`, too.

In your case the first mixin won't compile, because you specify one parameter, but pass two.
In order to pass comma-separated list into mixin as one argument, use semicolon (`;`) as separator:

```
.transition(left 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;);
```

If you pass only one argument, your both mixins do basically same thing.

You can read more [in the docs](http://lesscss.org/#-parametric-mixins) - scroll down a bit to reach "The `@arguments` variable".

Comment: That's the thing I oversaw, there actually was a semicolon at the end in our mixin call. This way it works with both @arguments and ellipsis...

Comment: Still have to mark the other answer as solution, because technically there is a difference.

Comment: Sure. I must've failed to express my thought in right words - I wanted to say that as long as one argument is passed, there is no difference. I've edited my answer to make it clearer.